# How to find `npm i -g` cache path for macOS?

Tags: npm

I try to run `npm i -g electron` but I can't download the required files due to network restriction (like electron-v1.8.3-darwin-x64.zip). I have these files locally I just need to put them into the cache folder (it is not electron-builder's `~/Library/Caches/electron-builder`) so it can install without needing to the download the files.

npm typically download files to: `/private/var/folders/mp/{{random}}/T/electron-tmp-download-56623-{{timestamp}}/`

Because this isn't a static path, if I simply put files into the existing folder it won't work. npm will try to download to a new path (stupid).

If I use `npm cache add file/folder` of this random path or files I already have, it will return:

```
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/folders/mp/{{random}}/T/electron-tmp-download-56623-{{timestamp}}/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the [`npm cache`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) command you can add the file directly. eg:

```
npm cache add electron-v1.8.3-darwin-x64.zip
```

When done use `npm cache clean` to reset the cache

Comment: also `npm cache` doesn't seem to work on files see my question update.

Comment: afterwards, you can use `npm cache clean`

Comment: are you trying to install Electron? because you can do so directly [from GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases)

Comment: Yes, except github is very slow in China.

Comment: Are there any file hosting sites closer to you? I could upload the file and give you a link?

Comment: Thx mate, I just left the computer on over night to get it installed. But appreciate the effort. Usually pan.baidu.com is the file hosting service used in China.

Comment: glad you got it working :) would you be able to mark the question as answered so other people don't come in?

Comment: well the question itself is not even answered.